# Status bar color in iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Thanks for taking your time to help others.

**[This is the original post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/722538), I publish here also hoping for better luck. Thanks!**

### Problem description:

Our SwiftUI app min deployment is iOS 14. We've been struggling with **status bar** color just in iOS 16.

**We can't change its color/appearance from light to dark.**

### Previous valid solution (iOS 13 to iOS 15)

Since now we used to manage the appearance with ...

1- Call in specific view, when a condition is given, like no dark mode supported, or side menu have been open

```
UIApplication.setStatusBarStyle(.darkContent)
```

2- The extension to support this on any SwiftUI View

```
import UIKit

extension UIApplication {
    class func setStatusBarStyle(_ style: UIStatusBarStyle) {
        if let controller = UIApplication.getKeyWindow()?.rootViewController as? ContentHostingController {
            controller.changeStatusBarStyle(style)
        }
    }
}
```

3- Actually, the controller class

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

class ContentHostingController: UIHostingController<AnyView> {

  private var currentStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle = .default

  override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    currentStatusBarStyle
  }

  func changeStatusBarStyle(_ style: UIStatusBarStyle) {
    self.currentStatusBarStyle = style
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
  }
}
```

**But**, as I said, this stopped working with iOS 16.

### What we have checked?

As we googled it...

1. Using .preferredColorScheme modifier, changes the app appearance, and we want to keep, for example, the dark theme along light status bar. So it's not an option.
2. Applying .toolbarColorScheme (iOS 16), does nothing.
3. Manage Info.plist without success. Light content by default, could
   be changed (with the method described above)

### Questions

1. Why is this not working in iOS 16? Are we doing something wrong?
   (worked like a charm for 13 to 15).
2. Is there any generic (iOS 13 to 16) way that you actually use and
   work?
3. (If not) Do you know any workaround to apply on 16 only?

### Final solution (by @ashley-mills and refined by me):

First, a View extension to keep it clean:

```
func iOS16navBarAdapter(_ colorScheme: ColorScheme) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16, *) {
            return self
                .toolbarBackground(Color.navigationBar, for: .navigationBar)
                .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
                .toolbarColorScheme(colorScheme, for: .navigationBar)
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
```

You can use as follows on your view:

```
@State private var iOS16colorScheme: ColorScheme = .dark

...

VStack {
    ...
}
.iOS16navBarAdapter(iOS16colorScheme)
.onChange(of: globalSideMenu.xCoord) { value in
    iOS16colorScheme = value > sideMenuOffset ? .light : .dark
}
```

Comment: The solution seems to be working only if the navigationBar is visible, is there anyway to makes it works for hidden nav bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to change the status bar colour.

Starting with this `View`:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.mint
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

and setting the following **info.plist** keys:

- View controller-based status bar appearance: **NO**
- Status bar style: **Dark Content**

gives:

[image]

Changing

- Status bar style: **Light Content**

gives:

[image]

You can also change the status bar text colour on a per view basis, making sure you set

- View controller-based status bar appearance: **YES**

then wrapping your view in a `NavigationStack`, and adding the following `toolbar` modifiers:

```
.toolbarBackground(.mint, for: .navigationBar)
.toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
.toolbarColorScheme(<colorScheme>, for: .navigationBar)
```

for example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TestView(colorScheme: .dark)
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    
    let colorScheme: ColorScheme
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.mint
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Text("Hello")
                NavigationLink("Push") {
                    TestView(colorScheme: .dark)
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbarBackground(.mint, for: .navigationBar)
        .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
        .toolbarColorScheme(colorScheme, for: .navigationBar)
    }
}
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Ashley! We were just setting it in wrong order.